# LTI system impulse response output

Tags: linear-systems, impulse-response

If I have a LTI system which has impulse response $h(n) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nu(n)$   and the entry is $x[n]=u[n]-u[n-1]$ where $u[n]$ is the unit step function. In order to find the output I have to convolute the $h[n]$ with $u[n]$ and knowing $x(n)=u[n]-u[n-1]\Longrightarrow y(n)=h(n)+h(n-1)$ take the result. Is my thought right? Because I saw somewhere some examples solving differently.

for the above example the result is $y[n]=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nu(n)-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}u(n-1)  $

(there is a similar question [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/lti-system-output) but I have confused from the discussion.)

Comment: Is $x[n]$ now equal to $u[n]-u[n-1]$ or $u[n]+u[n-1]$? Both occur in your question.

Comment: I am sorry,  my fault, the correct is,t: $x[n]=u[n]−u[n−1]$.
Is the answer right?

Comment: You should correct this in your question to avoid further misunderstandings. Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: That's right, and the user reminded me of that other question. So let's delete one of them ...

Comment: @MattL. So you _could_ vote to close this one (or flag it for deletion)....

Comment: @DilipSarwate If there is any problem, you can delete this topic( understand it), also I found the other topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input signal is

$$x[n]=u[n]-u[n-1]$$

then it is in fact a unit impulse: $x[n]=\delta[n]$, which has only one non-zero value for $n=0$ ($x[0]=1$). All other values are zero. So the response to this input signal is the system's impulse response, because that's the definition of the impulse response: $y[n]=h[n]$

Note that $u[n]$ is the unit step, and the response to a unit step is not the impulse response but the step response. But for this example you don't need to compute the step response, because, as already mentioned, the input signal is simply a unit impulse.

Comment: so $y[n]=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nu(n)-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}u(n-1) $ is correct. right? the output is directly obtained from $y(n)=h(n)-h(n-1)$

Comment: @EricP.: No, as I said in my answer: $y[n]=h[n]$. If the input is an impulse, the output must be the impulse response.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your time.

I am sorry I meant, (my fault again forgot to change the symbols in copy-paste the  latex formula): $y[n]=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nh[n]-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}h[n-1] $

Comment: @EricP.: No, $y[n]=h[n]$, I don't know how to make it any clearer. The input is an impulse, so the output is the impulse response given by $h[n]$. So no need to compute anything etc.

Comment: Well,

I have a LTI system which has:
Impulse response $h(n) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nu(n)$ and an entry $x[n]=u[n]-u[n-1]$ where $u[n]$ unit step function.                                                The output $y[n]=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nu(n)$ ? I have confused I must search for some theory about the topic :(

Comment: @EricP.: Yes, you got it. Please take the time to read my answer once more, and try to understand that $x[n]=\delta[n]$. From this it follows that the output must equal the impulse response.

Comment: Thanks @Matt L.  I appreciate your patience and thanks again for your time. I will read your answer again.

Also, your answer here is similar (on the same topic). Can check it ? http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/lti-system-output?rq=1

Comment: @EricP.: I updated the other answer to show that both answers are the same.

Comment: I think I have understand it now. One more question, If the entry was different for example $x[n]=u[n]-u[n-2]$ and all other remain the same. The output will be the same? $ y[n]=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nu(n)$

Comment: @EricP.: No, different inputs in general result in different outputs.